# Working out the area of a triangle within another triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

[image]

> The area of $\triangle OBF$ is $5$ cm$^2$. $F$ is a point on $OA$ such that $OF = \dfrac9{11}OA$. Work out the area of $\triangle OBA$.

I have tried to solve this problem for a while, and just can't figure out how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Observe that both $\triangle OBF$ and $\triangle AOB$ have same height on bases $OF$ and $AO$
[image]

Here DE is perpendicular for $\triangle DCB$

Comment: Why though? How would you define the height of the triangle on base OF or OA? I thought that the height was the length of the line drawn from the top vertex that makes a right angle with the base. With OF or OA as the base that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: See OF and OA are common lines. i.e. OF lies on OA. So perpendicular from B to both OF and OA will be common

Comment: Still, I don't understand how that proves that the height remains the same.

Comment: Do you know that perpendicular from a point to a line is always distinct?

Comment: You may draw the height of both triangles and see

Comment: But you cannot draw a perpendicular to OF or OA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78264/discussion-between-usernamesarehard-and-love-invariants).

Comment: @usernamesAreHard-Now check it

Comment: Ahh, right. I see it now. Thanks for the help, I appreciate your time.

Comment: @usernamesAreHard- You're welcome